# Debugging with visual studio multi-threaded app

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am writing a threaded application.

I need a way to see the current active threads while debugging, I have tried to place a break point - but i only see the current running thread.

i need a way to inspect the other threads that are currently running as well.
is there any tool/method i can use to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the built in Threads Window, while execution is at your selected break point
you can open the threads window going to **debug->Windows->Threads**

it will give you extensive information on all open threads.

you can read all about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx

Comment: Great, exactly what i needed. i think the threads option window is only available while in debug state.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the VS thread window for this situations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms164746%28v=vs.100%29.aspx